# Create bigger screensize with scrollbar

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a task, a screen where I want to give the user information in the form of text view of strings and I want to give the user a few choices by including radio buttons.
The problem is it will not fit on the screen. Therefore, I would enlarge the screen so I can add more things. But how?
I have tested with scroll view and various layouts but I don't get it to work.

Below I have my code that I have so far. I have two buttons that should always be at the bottom.

I hope someone can help me. :)

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".SetupActivity" >

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout2"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="18dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnMain"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:onClick="MainActivity"
        android:paddingLeft="8dp"
        android:paddingRight="8dp"
        android:text="@string/btnCalori" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnSetup"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="@string/btnSetup" />
</LinearLayout>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txtViewSetup"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:text="@string/txtViewSetup" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txtViewHeader1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/linearLayout2"
    android:layout_below="@+id/txtViewSetup"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:text="@string/txtViewAttribut" />

<RadioButton
    android:id="@+id/radioBtnFemale"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/txtViewHeader1"
    android:layout_below="@+id/txtViewHeader1"
    android:text="@string/strFemale" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txtViewHeader2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/radioBtnMale"
    android:layout_below="@+id/radioBtnMale"
    android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
    android:text="@string/txtViewWeight" />

<RadioButton
    android:id="@+id/radioBtnMale"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/radioBtnFemale"
    android:layout_below="@+id/radioBtnFemale"
    android:text="@string/strMale" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: @Robert Jarlvik where is scrollView in your code??

Comment: @MaciejGórski I need more reputitions (?) to post a image.

Comment: @Pratik Well, I did'nt get it to work that's why. I only show the code that actually works here. But I need the screen height to be bigger..

Comment: You are welcome to answer some questions here to get more reputation.

Comment: @RobertJarlvik if you want to add vertically no of elements then you can use scrollView.

Comment: Thank you @MaciejGórski and @Pratik! I got my question answered down below! :)

Answer (score 0):

`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>`

`<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"`
`xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"`
`android:layout_width="match_parent"`
`android:layout_height="wrap_content"`
`tools:context=".SetupActivity" >`

`<TextView`
  `android:id="@+id/txtViewSetup"`
   `android:layout_width="wrap_content"`
   `android:layout_height="wrap_content"`
 `android:layout_alignParentTop="true"`
 `android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"`
  `android:text="@string/txtViewSetup" />`

`<ScrollView`
 `android:id="@+id/scrollview"`
`android:layout_below="@+id/txtViewSetup"`
`android:layout_width="fill_parent"`
`android:layout_height="match_parent"`
`android:layout_marginBottom="50dp" >`

`<LinearLayout`
`android:layout_width="fill_parent"`
`android:layout_height="wrap_content"`
`android:orientation="vertical" >`

`<TextView`
`android:id="@+id/txtViewHeader1"`
`android:layout_width="wrap_content"`
`android:layout_height="wrap_content"`
`android:layout_marginTop="5dp"`
`android:text="@string/txtViewAttribut" />`

`<RadioButton`
`android:id="@+id/radioBtnFemale"`
`android:layout_width="wrap_content"`
`android:layout_height="wrap_content"`
`android:layout_marginTop="5dp"`
`android:text="@string/strFemale" />`

`<RadioButton`
`android:id="@+id/radioBtnMale"`
`android:layout_width="wrap_content"`
`android:layout_height="wrap_content"`
`android:text="@string/strMale" />`

`<TextView`
`android:id="@+id/txtViewHeader2"`
`android:layout_width="wrap_content"`
`android:layout_height="wrap_content"`
`android:layout_marginTop="5dp"`
`android:text="@string/txtViewWeight" />`

`</LinearLayout>`

`</ScrollView>`

`<LinearLayout`
`android:id="@+id/linearLayout2"`
`android:layout_width="fill_parent"`
`android:layout_height="wrap_content"`
`android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"`
`android:orientation="horizontal" >`

`<Button`
`android:id="@+id/btnMain"`
`android:layout_width="fill_parent"`
`android:layout_height="wrap_content"`
`android:layout_weight="1"`
`android:onClick="MainActivity"`
`android:paddingLeft="8dp"`
`android:paddingRight="8dp"`
`android:text="@string/btnCalori" />`

`<Button`
`android:id="@+id/btnSetup"`
`android:layout_width="fill_parent"`
`android:layout_height="wrap_content"`
`android:layout_weight="1"`
`android:text="@string/btnSetup" />`
`</LinearLayout>`

`</RelativeLayout>`

Comment: Thanks, that was exactly the answer I was looking for. Sorry I can not make your answer to an answer by voting.